# How to access Facebook video library

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> I created c# application to access Facebook using Facebook sdk,It's
>   working ok but i want to access video library from videos category.
>  I
>   searched a lot but i can not find any related thing.

[image]

Comment: What's that supposed to show, the videos that have been posted by a page? Well then you'd be looking for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/, obviously.

Comment: this reference does not include videolibrary documented i lready read it before very well but it does not talking about how to access video library or publishing tools in Facebook.I need it to upload videos into it as upload video through "https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/video " posted videos in page feed also videos category only and i want to posted it also in video library for business needs.

Answer (score 0):

i finally find the solution just add parameter unpublished_content_type to Facebook API request to any of values which needed {SCHEDULED, DRAFT, ADS_POST} then video upload to video library.